how to improve CNN for classifying images
have a CNN model to classify images: images are yes or no, some have checkboxes some are circled (or not)
and my aim is to hqve the model predict to which class they belong.
so created 4 folders: circled, not_circled,ticked, not_ticked
to increase the number of images for each category i processed
the images to change the resoltion (80x80, 120x80).
The number of images is more or less same across categories.
Number of images per label in the entire dataset:
ticked (0): 366 images
unticked (1): 353 images
circled_yes (2): 359 images
circled_no (3): 341 images
The model summary says i have 2M parameters, accuracy is 98.2%
is there a way i can improve?
tried to reduce parameters but got worse performances.
the code i am using so far
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import logging
import random

# Set the random seeds for reproducibility
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "0"
random.seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)
os.environ["TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS"] = "1"

# Initialize logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Load and preprocess images
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    folder_path = os.path.join(current_dir, folder)
    LOGGER.info(f"Folder path is {folder_path}")
    images = []
    labels = []

    if not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        raise ValueError(f"Folder {folder_path} does not exist.")

    for label in os.listdir(folder_path):
        LOGGER.info(f"Processing label: {label}")
        if label == "images_test":
            continue
        label_folder = os.path.join(folder_path, label)
        LOGGER.info(f"Label '{label}' folder is {label_folder}")
        if not os.path.isdir(label_folder):
            continue
        # Walk through the label folder and its subfolders
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(label_folder):
            for file in files:
                img_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                # LOGGER.info(f"Processing image {img_path}")
                img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Load image in grayscale
                if img is not None:
                    img = cv2.resize(img, (80, 140))  # Resize to 80x140 (width x height) for the model
                    images.append(img)
                    labels.append(label)
                else:
                    LOGGER.warning(f"Failed to load image {img_path}")
        # Removed the 'break' statement to allow processing all labels

    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)


# Load data
LOGGER.info("Loading images from dataset")
image_data, labels = load_images_from_folder("dataset/")
image_data = image_data.reshape(-1, 140, 80, 1)  # Add channel dimension for grayscale
image_data = image_data / 255.0  # Normalize the pixel values

# Convert labels to integers (e.g., ticked=0, unticked=1, circled_yes=2, circled_no=3)
LOGGER.info("Labeling images")
label_mapping = {"ticked": 0, "unticked": 1, "circled_yes": 2, "circled_no": 3}
labels = np.array([label_mapping[label] for label in labels])

# Count the number of images per label
unique_labels, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
label_names = {v: k for k, v in label_mapping.items()}  # Reverse mapping
print("\nNumber of images per label in the entire dataset:")
for label_int, count in zip(unique_labels, counts):
    label_name = label_names[label_int]
    print(f"{label_name} ({label_int}): {count} images")

# Split data into training, validation, and testing
LOGGER.info("Splitting data into training, validation, and testing")
X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(image_data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
    X_train_full, y_train_full, test_size=0.1, random_state=42
)  # 10% of training data for validation


# Function to count labels
def count_labels(y, dataset_name):
    unique_labels, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
    print(f"\nNumber of images per label in the {dataset_name} set:")
    for label_int, count in zip(unique_labels, counts):
        label_name = label_names[label_int]
        print(f"{label_name} ({label_int}): {count} images")


# Count labels in each dataset
count_labels(y_train, "training")
count_labels(y_val, "validation")
count_labels(y_test, "testing")

# Compute class weights
class_weights_array = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight="balanced", classes=np.unique(y_train), y=y_train)
class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights_array))

# Create the CNN model
LOGGER.info("Creating CNN model with dropout")
model = models.Sequential()

# First convolutional block
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(140, 80, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))  # Dropout layer added

# Second convolutional block
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))  # Dropout layer added

# Third convolutional block
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
# Optional pooling layer if needed
# model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))  # Dropout layer added

# Flatten and dense layers
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))  # Dropout layer added
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax"))

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", factor=0.1, patience=3)

# Compile the model
LOGGER.info("Compiling the model")
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
# Train the model
LOGGER.info("Training the model")
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
    callbacks=[early_stopping, lr_scheduler],
    class_weight=class_weights,
)


print("")
print("")
print("")
print("")
print("")


# Plot training and validation accuracy and loss
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(history.history["accuracy"], label="Training Accuracy", color="blue")
plt.plot(history.history["val_accuracy"], label="Validation Accuracy", color="orange")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.title("Model Accuracy")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(history.history["loss"], label="Training Loss", color="blue")
plt.plot(history.history["val_loss"], label="Validation Loss", color="orange")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.title("Model Loss")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Evaluate the model on test data
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
LOGGER.info(f"Test accuracy: {test_acc}")


# Evaluate the model
LOGGER.info("\nEvaluating the model")
LOGGER.info("Classification Report")
y_pred_probs = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred_probs, axis=1)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=label_mapping.keys()))

and gives me 98% accuracy and a validation loss (that decreased monotonically during training) of 0.2698
The final report is:
precision    recall  f1-score   support

      ticked       0.96      0.97      0.96        69
    unticked       0.97      0.95      0.96        59
 circled_yes       0.99      1.00      0.99        79
  circled_no       1.00      0.99      0.99        70

    accuracy                           0.98       277
   macro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98       277
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98       277

trying to add more images to dataset but seems to decrease performances, so I am stuck
augmenting seems to confuse the model amd the accuracy reduces
any tips to improve the model?
some examples of images:




Classification Report
    precision    recall  f1-score   support

      ticked       1.00      0.96      0.98        75
    unticked       0.96      1.00      0.98        74
 circled_yes       1.00      1.00      1.00        71
  circled_no       1.00      1.00      1.00        64

    accuracy                           0.99       284
   macro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99       284
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99       284

INFO:__main__:Confusion Matrix:
 [[72  3  0  0]
 [ 0 74  0  0]
 [ 0  0 71  0]
 [ 0  0  0 64]]


I have some suggestions to improve you training results.

Avoid augmentations that make the changes the original label of the image. For example, if you have a circle at one of the image corners and you do random center crop then you will lose that circle but the image is still being labelled with circled.

I see that you are loading all the images into numpy array. This is not memory efficient (unless you have limited data size). It is better to use a dataloader instead


These are general tips, but would help if we get more information about your use case:

How many images in total you have ?
Do you have class inbalance ? Make sure you have balance in the training data.
Could you share some examples of the images ?


for augmentatiom i meant reading some random image for a class and change its resolutiom ad add it to same class folder. just to increase numbdr of images available

Got it! thanks for the clarification. The accuracy you are getting is already pretty high so to improve it further I suggest to follow a data driven analysis. Try to see where the model fails the most and check the data samples and try to spot any edge cases. Also for augmentation, you can try color based augmentations like changing the brightness, contrat etc. Have a look at https://albumentations.ai/docs/introduction/image_augmentation/

i increased numver of neurons to 128 and then set epochs=200, learning_rate=0.0002 this increased accuracy to 98.94. i added to question my full report. is just i dont want false positives.

I don't think reaching zero false positives in achievable in real case scenario. You will always have some samples where the model mispredicts the labels. Also, if the test set you are using is very similar (in terms of distribution) to you training set then the performance you are getting might not be indicative enough. Try to evaluate the model on samples that are not very similar to the images you have.
